# How do I create a regex that contains a variable and comments?

Tags: python, regex, windows

I'd like to create a regex that contains comments and a variable.  I thought I'd split up the string like so, but it doesn't work:

```
import re

regex = re.compile(r'''
        ^(sm\d{5}-[a-z]+-\d{2})          # study number''' + 
        doctype               +      r'''# document
        v(\d+)-(\d+)                     # version number
        \.pdf$                           # pdf extension
        ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Break your regex pattern into multiple strings, then combine them into a single string with `"".join()`, like so

```
import re
pattern = "".join([
    "^(sm\d{5}-[a-z]+-\d{2})",  # study number
    doctype,  # document
    "v(\d+)-(\d+)",  # version number
    "\.pdf$",  # pdf extension
])
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)
```

To avoid the need for comments, you might use descriptive variable names for each section of the regex. Doing it this way, it might also make sense to separate the line positioning characters from the "business logic" of your regex to make these variables more reusable.

```
study_number_pattern = "(sm\d{5}-[a-z]+-\d{2})"
version_number_pattern = "v(\d+)-(\d+)"
pdf_extension_pattern = "\.pdf"
pattern = "".join([
    "^",
    study_number_pattern,
    doctype,
    version_number_pattern,
    pdf_extension_pattern,
    "$"
])
regex = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE)
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you.

Comment: If this answer was helpful to you, please click the green checkmark to mark it as the "accepted answer". This shows other community members that the answer was useful and might have a high chance of helping them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation sign and a closing block of quotes (''') on the second line of the pattern were commented out along with your note; simply move them in front of the comment.
I put both plus signs on one line, but you could still have them split across multiple ones, that's simply my preference...

```
regex = re.compile(r'''
        ^(sm\d{5}-[a-z]+-\d{2})'''   # study number
        + doctype +                  # document
        r'''v(\d+)-(\d+)             # version number
        \.pdf$                       # pdf extension
        ''', re.VERBOSE)
```

On a related note, do you use an IDE or any text editor for writing code? If not, that would be quite helpful. Errors like this would be instantly caught and highlighted.

Edit:
Stack Overflow syntax highlighting makes it appear as though the lines with comments 'version number' and 'pdf extension' are part of the pattern in the code above, but using the re.VERBOSE flag makes them actual comments.

Comment: The regex in this answer does not match the intended pattern from the question since it includes the literal strings "# version number" and "# pdf extension".

Comment: @Emmett J. Butler re.VERBOSE makes them comments, despite what syntax on SO may show. Run it on a test string, like `sm12345-a-21some_doctypev3-3.pdf` with `doctype = 'some_doctype'`